# How to refresh variables in python3

Tags: python-3.x

i have some global variables declared like that :

```
piece = ''
sensor_name = 'ID_' + piece + '-'
```

my main function looks like :

```
if __main__ == "__main__":
     global piece, sensor_name
     piece = "value"
     print(piece) => show "value", it's ok
     print(sensor_name) => show "ID_-" and that's all.
```

When i print piece, i have the good value but the sensor_name variable hasn't got the good content because it thinks piece variable is still empty.
What can I do to solve this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Format the code properly.

Comment: Perhaps `sensor_name` should be a function that returns the proper string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look...

```
piece = ''
sensor_name = 'ID_' + piece + '-'   #variable sensor_name interperted here only ans assigned a value of 'ID_-'

if __name__ == "__main__":    #__main__ should be __name__
     global piece, sensor_name   #Yes you can use variable with global to any function in file/class
     piece = "value"
     sensor_name = 'ID_' + piece + '-' #place this code here to have desired output
     print(piece) => show "value", it's ok
     print(sensor_name) => show "ID_-" and that's all.
```

Comment: So, our global variables have to be declared in the main funtion ?
Will the variable be  global to every functions called in __main__ ?
Thanks for the help !